# List comprehension currency conversion pass statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, currency

I am trying to write list comprehension to convert currencies in a pandas dataframe to all usd. I am using the forex_python.converter to get the exchange rates.

the data looks like:

| Amount | Currency | Amount_USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | usd |  |
| 45 | cad |  |
| 17 | gbp |  |

I want to write a loop to apply the exchange rate of a particular day to convert each row to usd, but if the row is usd then Amount_USD should just equal Amount

So far I have tried:

```
for currency in currencies:
    if currency == 'usd':
        data['Amount_USD'] == data['Amount']
    else:
        date_obj=datetime.datetime(2020,8,1)
        currency2 = print('"{0}"'.format(currency))
        rate = c.get_rate(currency2,'USD', date_obj)
        data['Amount_USD'] = np.where(data['Currency']== currency2, data['Amount']*rate , np.nan)
```

But currently the code is applying an exchange rate to USD values.

Comment: why are you doing `currency2 = print('"{0}"'.format(currency))`?

Comment: there's probably a better way but for the c.get_rate() statement it needs the currency to be in quotes ('usd'). Without using the formatter the currency only comes up at usd with no quotes

Comment: What does that have to do with `print`? You realized, `currency2 == None`, correct?

Comment: I simplified the solution code - rate=1 for USD now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this rewrite:

```
for currency in currencies:
    if currency != 'usd':
        date_obj=datetime.datetime(2020,8,1)
        currency2 = print('"{0}"'.format(currency))
        rate = c.get_rate(currency2,'USD', date_obj)
    else:
        rate = 1
    data.loc[data.currency == currency, 'Amount_USD'] = data['Amount'] * rate
```